# How to get to the prompt to type sql commands in Linux?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04

```
~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
 * Starting MySQL database server mysqld                                                                                         [ OK ] 
~$
```

This worked, but I want the prompt where I can type the SQL commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysql -u root -p`

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

`mysql -u username -p` this will prompt you for a password and then ENTER

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql client.

mysql -uusername -ppassword

Answer (score 0):

`mysql -u username -p`  and hit enter. Hope this will work.

and if you also want direct access. So try this command:

```
mysql -uUsername -pPassword DB_Name
```